# Send a file to another computer when you know it's IP using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, ip

How would I send a file from one computer to another using only a batch file if I know the IP of the receiving computer? Could this be done with net send? Could it be copied to their desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNC paths if the other computer has file sharing enabled, e.g.:

```
copy file.txt \\1.2.3.4\c$\
```

Comment: What's a UNC? and is file sharing on by default? And how could I choose the exact location of the file? Could I then make it run?